# Update table through using multiple joins MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables

**activity**

[image]

**activity_bak**

[image]

I want to take the comments from **activity_bak** and update the comments in **activity** to match by using the corresponding activity_no and activity_seq.

I've tried doing it like this but to no success:

```
update Animal.sysadm.activity
       set activity_comment = ab.activity_comment
           from Animal.SYSADM.activity a
               left join Animal.SYSADM.activity_bak ab
          on ab.activity_no = a.activity_no
               left join Animal.sysadm.activity_bak ab2
          on ab2.activity_seq = a.activity_seq
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No need to do 2 joins, you need just one. The right syntax is:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.activity_comment = ab.activity_comment
FROM Animal.SYSADM.activity a
INNER JOIN Animal.SYSADM.activity_bak ab
    ON ab.activity_no = a.activity_no
    AND ab.activity_seq = a.activity_seq;
```

Comment: Ah.  I should've known that.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you want:

```
update A set activity_comment = ab.activity_comment
    from Animal.SYSADM.activity a
    left join Animal.SYSADM.activity_bak ab
        on ab.activity_no = a.activity_no
        And ab.activity_seq = a.activity_seq
```